# Work Manager sending wrong input data to the Worker class when performing periodic work request in my activity. How to fix it?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

I am performing a **Periodic Work Request** in my activity using **Work Manager**, and want to send data from my activity to the Worker class using `setInputData()`. I am sending flightnumber and departuredate to my Worker class, however, it does not recognise flightnumber in my worker class and either prints `null` or just the departure date even when I am reading flight number in my Worker class. Why is it not reading flightnumber and just the departure date? Below is the code -

**Activity**

```
final PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest1 = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(SendNotification.class,15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                            .setInputData(new Data.Builder()
                            .putString(SendNotification.FLIGHTNUMBER, flightNumber)
                            .putString(SendNotification.DATE, departure_date).build())
                            .build();

                    WorkManager workManager =  WorkManager.getInstance(FlightDescriptionActivity.this);

                    workManager.enqueue(periodicWorkRequest1);

                    workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(periodicWorkRequest1.getId())
                            .observe(FlightDescriptionActivity.this, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onChanged(@Nullable WorkInfo workInfo) {
                                    if (workInfo != null) {
                                        Log.d("periodicWorkRequest", "Status changed to : " + workInfo.getState());

                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

**Class extending Worker**

```
public class SendNotification extends Worker {

    public static final String FLIGHTNUMBER="";
    public static  final String DATE = "";

    public SendNotification(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        String flightnumber = getInputData().getString(FLIGHTNUMBER); //this gets read as data, what can be the reason?
        String date = getInputData().getString(DATE);

        sendNotification(flightnumber,date); //it prints date for flightnumber as well, and sometimes it just passes null data

        return Result.success();

    }}
```

I am stuck on this for really long, any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you try OneTimeWorkRequest?

Answer (score 0):

have a try via updating the following code

```
workManager.enqueue(periodicWorkRequest1);
```

to

```
workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("check_notification", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, periodicWorkRequest1);
```

Comment: Please clearify why you suggest this change. This would help the questioner to understand the reason for the change.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.